# Sort files by extension with recursive function in js

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodes, fs

I have a function which get me all the files in folder recursively but i want to sort them by only few specific extension , I know i can use glob but how do i do that using fs in node

```
const fs = require('fs');
function getFiles (dir, files_){
files_ = files_ || [];
var files = fs.readdirSync(dir);
for (var i in files){
    var name = dir + '/' + files[i];
    if (fs.statSync(name).isDirectory()){
        getFiles(name, files_);
    } else {
        files_.push(name);
    }
}
return files_;
}
console.log(getFiles('D:/sample'))
```

Comment: Can you provide examples of possible input list and expectet result list?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could add conditional logic before pushing the files into files_ array, and then using string methods to check the last 4 elements of files[i] if it matches a certain extension, and if it does, proceed to push that file into files_.

```
  const fs = require('fs');
  function getFiles (dir, files_) {
    files_ = files_ || [];
    var files = fs.readdirSync(dir);
    var parseThese = [".txt", ".pdf", ".csv"];
    
    for (var i in files) {
      var name = dir + '/' + files[i];
      var extension = "";

      if (fs.statSync(name).isDirectory()) {
        return getFiles(name, files_);
      } 

      extension = files[i].slice(-4);
      if (parseThese.includes(extension)) {
        return files_.push(name);
      }
    }
    return files_;
 }
 console.log(getFiles('D:/sample'))
```

It's not using the FS module, but perhaps this could work.